Clear google sheets cell content when the value of dropdown changes

As you can see in the image above, I want to be able to clear certain cells whenever the values in either of the dropdown changes in GOOGLE SHEETS
I am just trying to figure it out please help me :)


add this script:


function clearRanges() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Define the ranges to clear
  var ranges = [
    'A2:A7',
    'C1:D1',
    'D6',
    'B2:C9'
  ];
  
  // Loop through each range and clear the contents
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(ranges[i]).clear();
 }}


change ranges as you need
add button
associate button with script
press button



update
to associate it with dropdown change (either F3 or F4) try:
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the active sheet and the edited range
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  
  // Check if the edited cell is F3 or F4
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && (range.getA1Notation() == "F3" || range.getA1Notation() == "F4")) {
    // Define the ranges to clear
    var ranges = [
      'A2:A7',
      'C1:D1',
      'D6',
      'B2:C9'
    ];
    
    // Loop through each range and clear the contents
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(ranges[i]).clear();
 }}}


hey, thanks but I want to clear cells only if the dropdown value changes. how to I make it associated with the dropdown change event?
